# Bash recursive function with for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, recursion, process

In a root folder, I have a subfolder structure containing some mp3-files. I want to copy all subfolders and the mp3-files to an sd-card, which can be read by an mp3-player. Simply copying the entire root folder to the card messes up the mp3-file order. This problem is known an documented in the internet. One solution is to use rsync, which does not work for me - the other is to copy the files one after the other and with that the order is fine for my player.
So I wrote a bash script to walk through my subfolder structure, create the some subfolders on the sd-card and copy the mp3-files into them. Since my subfolder structure is kind of random, I decided to write a recursive function to be called in each subfolder like this:

```
ScanKo () 
{
  cd "$1"
  for i in *
  do
    if [[ -d "$i" ]]
    then
      mkdir -p "$2/$i"
      ScanKo "$1/$i" "$2/$i"
    elif [[ "${i##*.}" = "mp3" ]]
    then
      cp "$1/$i" "$2/$i"
    fi
  done
}

ScanKo "/home/monkey/source_root/" "/media/stick/destiny_root/"
```

The function ScanKo gets two parameters: source and destiny root folders. I cd into the source folder and use a for loop to scan through everything. If I hit a subfolder, I create this one on the destiny point (the sd-card) and call the function again with the subfolders as the parameters. If I hit an mp3-file, I copy it to the destiny. It only works in theory. It seems, that bash looses its context, as soon as a child function returns to its mother from it was called.

I resolved this by implementing the same approach with a recursive process. The according bash script for the process with the name "sdMachen" looks like this:

```
cd "$1"
for i in *
do
  if [[ -d "$i" ]]
  then
    mkdir -p "$2/$i"
    bash "$3/${0##*/}" "$1/$i" "$2/$i" "$3"
  elif [[ "${i##*.}" = "mp3" ]]
  then
    cp "$1/$i" "$2/$i"
  fi
done
```

I call the script on the command line with three parameters:

```
bash sdMachen "/home/monkey/source_root/" "/media/stick/destiny_root/" "$(pwd)"
```

I need the third parameter, just so I can go back the location where sdMachen is located. The part

> "$3/${0##*/}"

is needed just so the right bash script is found each time. Basically it is equivalent to

> /folder-where-script-is/sdMachen

It works with the recursive process - but why does it not work with the recursive bash function?

Comment: Maybe you should `cd -` before returning from the function?

Comment: right off the bat I see two primary issues ... *1)* at the beginning of each function call you `cd` down/into a directory but you never `cd` up/from a directory with the net result being that once you've `cd'd` into a series of subdirectories your code is left stranded at that lower level; quick-n-easy solution: add a `cd ..` at the end of the function (though there may be some edge cases to address) and ...

Comment: ... *2)* the variable `i` (global by default) is being redefined on each function call which means upon returning from a function call the 'parent' function's `i` contains the value of the 'child' function's `i`; at the beginning of the function consider adding `local i` to insure each function call is working with a local version of `i` (NOTE: this may not be an issue in *this* particular case because of your actual code but generally speaking you usually want to localize loop variables when dealing with nested function calls

Comment: You might (I haven't tested this) be able to avoid the `cd` and variable `i` problems by putting the recursive call in a subshell: `( ScanKo "$1/$i" "$2/$i" )`.  The `cd` and the modifications to `i` in the subshell will then have no effect in the caller.

Comment: On immediate problem I can spot, is `cp "$1/$i" "$2/$i"`: Onless you can ensure that `$1` is an **absolute** path to some directory, it does not make sense (since you did a `cd $1` before).

Comment: @choroba a "cd .." instead of a "cd -" at the function end does the trick like markp-fuso suggests

Comment: @markp-fuso "cd .." was missing. With that it works. A "local i" before the loop did not change the output

Comment: @pjh The subshell works too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many pitfalls associated with DIY recursive filesystem traversal in shell code.  Apart from the `cd` issue that you encountered, other common problems include the fact that `*` doesn't expand to all of the entries in a directory by default, and symbolic links can cause infinite loops in code that doesn't handle them carefully.  Fortunately there are established safe mechanisms for doing recursive traversals safely.  The [globstar](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#globstar_.28since_bash_4.0-alpha.29) mechanism in Bash is one of them.  It was introduced in Bash 4.0 but was vulnerable to crashes caused by circular symlinks until Bash 4.3.

The traditional way to do recursive traversal in shell code is to use [find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_(Unix)).  This [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code demonstrates one way to use `find` to solve your problem:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

srcroot=$1
destroot=$2

find "${srcroot/#-/.\/-}" -type f -name '*.mp3' -printf '%P\0'  \
    |   while IFS= read -r -d '' mp3path; do
            srcpath=$srcroot/$mp3path
            destpath=$destroot/$mp3path
            destdir=${destpath%/*}
            [[ -d $destdir ]] || mkdir -p -v -- "$destdir"
            cp -v -- "$srcpath" "$destpath"
        done
```

- I've presented the code as a standalone shell program but it's easy to incorporate it into a function if you want to do that.  Localize all of the variables that it uses.
- `"${srcroot/#-/.\/-}"` is normally the same as `"$srcroot"`, but it expands strings like `-dir1/dir2` to `./-dir1/dir2` to prevent strings that begin with `-` being treated as options, instead of directories, by `find`.  See [Substituting part of a string (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Substituting_part_of_a_string) for an explanation of the syntax.
- See [BashFAQ/001 (How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for an explanation of `find ... | while IFS= read -r -d '' ...`.  It ensures that the code can handle arbitrary file paths, including (unusual) ones that contain newline characters.
- See [Removing part of a string (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string) for an explanation of `${destpath%/*}`.
- `[[ -d $destdir ]] ||`  could be removed without breaking the code, but it might run significantly more slowly due to running many unnecessary `mkdir` processes.
- See [Bash Pitfalls #2 (cp $file $target)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cp_.24file_.24target) for an explanation of the `--` arguments in the `mkdir` and `cp` commands.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Bash, you can benefit from its `globstar` option to get all sub-directories as a flat list to work with:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ScanKo() {
    local srcDir=${1:?}
    local dstDir=${2:?}

    # Validates arguments
    [ -d "$srcDir" ] && [ -d "$dstDir" ] || exit 2

    # Saves globstar and nullglob options
    if shopt -q globstar; then local gs=s; else local gs=u; fi
    if shopt -q nullglob; then local ng=s; else local ng=u; fi

    # Sets globstar and nullglob options
    shopt -s globstar nullglob

    # Iterates source directory hierarchy with globstar **
    for dir in "$srcDir/"**/; do
        mkdir -p -- "${dstDir%/}${dir##$srcDir}"
    done

    # Restores globstar and nullglob as they where
    shopt "-$gs" globstar
    shopt "-$ng" nullglob
}

ScanKo "$@"
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out globstar and **/. I did not know about these before. How would I copy the mp3 files with this approach? I have found a workaround with the recursive process, so there is no desperate need for another fix. I want to understand, why the recursive function does not work.